# How can I call a parent constructor after some processing?

Tags: c++

I want to do some processing before the parent constructor is called. The following example shows why I want to do this despite the fact that I have made it slightly trivial for the sake of clarity. The real parent constructor is doing some rendering, but lets try and solve this problem first.

Essentially, the problem comes in when an overriden function is called by the parent constructor, but the child's data is not set up yet. How do I fix this?

```
class BaseClass {

public:
    int myNumber;

    BaseClass(){
        myNumber = 0;
        this->printNumber();
    }

    virtual void printNumber(){
        printf("My number is %d\n", this->myNumber);
    }
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass {

public:
    float childNumber;

    ChildClass(float myNumber) : BaseClass() {
        this->childNumber = myNumber;
    }

    void printNumber(){
        printf("My number is %f\n", this->childNumber);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others said above, you shouldn't call a virtual member from a constructor. But to address your problem there is an idiom that might help you, it is called base-from-member:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member

What it does basically, is take advantage of the fact that base classes are initialized in the order they are declared. You may be able to do what you need to do in a separate base class before your base class is initialized.

```
class OtherBaseClass {
    int Num;
    OtherBaseclass(float num) : Num(num)
    {
        printf("My number is %d\n", this->Num);
    }
};


class ChildClass : OtherBaseClass, BaseClass {

public:
    float childNumber;

    ChildClass(float myNumber) : OtherBaseClass(myNumber), BaseClass() {
....
```

Comment: And here is a _Boost_ implementation of said idiom: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/utility/base_from_member.html

Comment: You **can** call a virtual function from a constructor.

Answer (score 9):

> the problem comes in when an overriden function is called by the parent constructor,

No, that never happens. Within the constructor of `BaseClass` its dynamic type is `BaseClass` as well, so the `printNumber()` call will resolve to its own *number* instead of some derived class. Why? Because at that time the constructors for `ChildClass` has not yet finished running and so it wasn't yet created.

As *@FredLarson* comments, here is more info on the subject: http://parashift.com/c++-faq/calling-virtuals-from-ctors.html

Comment: More info on this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/calling-virtuals-from-ctors.html

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing out the error in my assumption. However, this isnt the answer to the question as stated in the title so I would feel bad as marking this as "the answer".

Comment: +1, but note, this specific answer points out that `printNumber()` in the base class would be invoked from the base class implementation if invoked from the base class constructor. For this example this is definitely true, thus the +1. However, you're in a world of hurt if your `memberFn()` is pure-virutal in the base class.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the constructor of the base class cannot call to the virtual function version of the derived class, that is, your `ChildClass::printNumber()` function **will not** be called.

That said, if you want to execute something before the constructor of the base class, one way to do it is using yet another base class, and put it before the other one:

```
class RunMeFirst
{
    public RunMeFirst()
    { printf("whatever...\n"); }
};

class ChildClass : private RunMeFirst, public BaseClass 
{ /*...*/ };
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to implement the rendering functionality in a base class?  Could you instead employ composition instead of inheritance.  Using composition would allow you to easily control the member initialization order, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

class renderer
{
public:

    renderer(int number)
    {
        std::cout << "Number is " << number << std::endl;
    }
};

class foo
{
public:

    foo()
        : number_(12)
        , renderer_(number_)
    {
    }

private:

    int number_;
    renderer renderer_;

};

int main()
{
    foo bar;
}
```

In general, [prefer composition to inheritance](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/codestandards3.html).  Also, the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) may be of use here, too, from a design point of view.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that run before a base class' constructor:

- Initialization of arguments
- Virtual base classes' constructors
- Other base classes declared earlier's constructors

One commonly used solution is called the "base from member idiom" and involves moving the member to a new base class that is constructed first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @K-ballo for pointing out the error and because of that I was able to restructure the code a bit to do what I wanted, but as this isnt a technical correct answer to the question either, Ill leave the correct answer as is.

```
class BaseClass {

public:
    int myNumber;

    BaseClass(bool initialize = true){
        myNumber = 0;
        if (initialize){
            this->initialize();
        }
    }

    void initialize(){
        this->printNumber();
    }

    virtual void printNumber(){
        printf("My number is %d\n", this->myNumber);
    }
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass {

public:
    float childNumber;

    ChildClass(float myNumber) : BaseClass(false) {
        this->childNumber = myNumber;
        this->initialize();
    }

    void printNumber(){
        printf("My number is %f\n", this->childNumber);
    }

}
```